# Perform unshift method on a copy of array

Tags: javascript

I want to unshift on a copy of the array, but the original array modifies too. Why is that?

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3]
var array2 = array1

array2.unshift(4, 5)

console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```

Comment: Objects are passed by reference

Comment: you don't have a copy of an array here, you are just referencing the original. You can use the spread syntax to make `array2` a shallow copy of `array1` (`var array2 = [...array1]`)

Comment: you assign the same object reference, not a new array. use `slice` for getting a copy

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thank you very much for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3]
var array2 = Array.from(array1)

array2.unshift(4, 5)

console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use spread operator`( ... )` to make second array. It will make a new array with new reference. And then perform your task.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [...array1];

array2.unshift(4, 5);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```